# PHP and HTML Table Trouble adding target="_blank"

Tags: php

```
  echo "<td><a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/" . $row['instagram'] . "\">$row[instagram]</a></td>";
```

I am trying to add target="_blank" to that somewhere just so when I click the link it opens in a new tab, for the life of me I can't get it.. I've tried it everywhere and every way it would exhaust me to retype all of them but this is my current line.

Comment: `<a target=\"_blank\" href...`

Comment: `... you're welcome`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.instagram.com/" . $row['instagram'] . "\">$row[instagram]</a>
```

It will add the `target` attribute to `_blank`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `target='_blank'`

```
echo "<td><a  target='_blank' href=\"https://www.instagram.com/" . $row['instagram'] . "\">$row[instagram]</a></td>";
```